# Get User's News Feed Using Javascript SDK Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can't seem to find a concrete answer since the Facebook SDK and permissions have changed over time. I am trying to create a Facebook app for webOS. I would be using the Javascript Facebook SDK making graph API calls. The most important part is that I need to get the user's news feed ( The first thing you see when you login to facebook ). Is it possible to get the user's news feed once they log in to my facebook app using the graph API? All of the code I have tried doesn't error out, but it does not return any information.

```
FB.api( '/me', 'GET', {fields: 'feed.limit(10)'},function( response ){ 

    console.log( response );

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without login, there is no access to ANY data of a user. And there is no way at all to get the feed, you can only get the user wall (his posts and posts of friends on his wall). You need to authorize users with the `user_posts` permission for that.

the API call: `/me/feed?limit=10`

with the JS SDK:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'GET', {limit: 10}, function(response) { 
    console.log( response );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, so I don't have all of my code posted. It's just the assumption the user has logged into my app. So when the user has logged in, there is no Graph API call to get the user's news feed. I guess Facebook doesn't want third party apps anymore. I know it was possible at one time.

Comment: yes, it was possible to get the news feed earlier, but it was removed for a good reason: third parties would be able to get access to posts of people who did not authorize the app. facebook does want third party apps, they just want to protect privacy ;)

Comment: it's kind of a bummer, there is no way to make a full app for a platform that does not have a Facebook app. The best I could do would be to create a wrapper to display the mobile site which is garbage. I will have to look into a way to inject my own stylesheets and js files into the wrapper